# In jQuery, can I use DataTables plugin after the Ajax function?

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatable

If I try to reload my dataTable no changes are made.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '../CustomJS/Service.asmx/GetCustomer',
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
    $('#dataTable').dataTable({
            data: data,
            sorting: true,
            searching : true,
            columns: [
                {
                    'data': 'CustomerID',
                    'sortable': false,
                    'searchable':false,
                    "render": function (id) {
                        return '<input type="checkbox" name="custSelect" data-columnIndex="'+id+'"/>'
                    }
                },
                {'data':'CustomerID'},
                {'data':'CustomerName'},
                {'data':'CustomerMobile'},
                {'data':'City'},
                {'data': 'Email' },
                {
                    'sortable': false,
                    'searchable': false,
                    'data': function (data, type, dataToSet) {
                        console.log("data",data)
                        if (data.Status == 1) {
                            return '<i class="far fa-edit update-icon" onclick=Update(' + data.CustomerID + ')></i><i class="fas fa-lock-open unlock-icon" onclick=Status('+data.CustomerID+',' + data.Status + ')></i><i class="fas fa-trash delete-icon" onclick=Delete(' + data.CustomerID + ')></i>';
                        } else {
                            return '<i class="far fa-edit update-icon" onclick=Update(' + data.CustomerID + ')></i><i class="fas fa-lock lock-icon" onclick=Status(' + data.Status + ',' + data.CustomerName + ')></i><i class="fas fa-trash delete-icon" onclick=Update(' + data.CustomerID + ')></i>';
                        }
                    },
                },
                {
                    'data': 'Status',
                    'sortable': false,
                    'searchable': false,
                    "render": function (active) {
                        if (active == 1) {
                            return '<label class="status-active">Active</label>';
                        } else {
                            return '<label class="status-in-active">In-Active</label>';
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        });

    },
    error: function (JqXHR, error, exception) {
        console.log("XHR", JqXHR.responseText);
        console.log("error", error);
        console.log("Exception", exception);
    }
});
```

Here I am Used to reload table,

table.dataTable().ajax.reload();

table.datatable().ajax.api().reload();

$('#dataTable').dataTable().api().reload();

$('#dataTable').DataTable().api().reload();

These are not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you've defined the DataTables within the Ajax success callback function - so this means DataTables doesn't know about the Ajax configuration, it was just initialised with the returned data.

To use DataTables' [`ajax.reload()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()) function, you need to define the Ajax configuration within the DataTables initialisation - take a look at the example [here](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html).